# Calculating Ka values from std. state thermodynamic data

Tags: aqueous-solution

My professor showed us a sample calculation of the Ka value for a strong acid. He used standard state thermodynamic data.

I have an issue with this:

1) Wouldn't this give us an understated Ka value?

2) Standard state conditions start with 1 molar solutions of solute. So in writing the reaction equation of an acid with water and by using that equation to find the delta G std. of reaction and then using the relationship between delta G and K to find K, wouldn't we be running into a sort of "common ion" effect issue? There's already a 1 molar concentration of hydronium ion IN solution under standard state conditions. Finding the K of an acid dissolving in water that has a pH of 0.0 doesn't give us a Ka value (or does it?)

EDIT to address Martin:

This is what he did:

$\ce{HNO_3 + H2O ->H_3O^+ +NO_3^-}$

Find ${\Delta G^o_r}$ for above reaction.

Use ${\Delta G^o_r=-RTlnK}$ to solve for K.

My question: Is this K that you find a $\ce{K_a}$ value?

Comment: It's worth remarking that the common ion effect is a consequence of the constancy of the equilibrium constant.  If you add nitric acid to an already acidic solution, the result is higher in H+ and lower in NO3- than if you added the acid to water, but the _product_ of these two concentrations divided by the concentration of undissociated nitric acid will be the same in the two cases.

Comment: Ohh I understand now! Thanks; that made a LOT of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $K_a$ for $\ce{HNO3}$ is $$\frac{[\ce{H3O+}][\ce{NO3-}]}{[\ce{HNO3}]}$$ (concentrations in mol/L), which is precisely the $K$ that you get from the $\Delta G_r^0 = -RT\ln K$ formula, assuming you use the right free energies (which is not a trivial matter since they must take into account the interaction of each species with surrounding water molecules, an effect known as solvation).

You may be wondering why the concentration of water does not appear in the equation for $K_a$ (or more generally the equation for $K$ in a reaction in aqueous solution).  Because that concentration remains essentially unchanged throughout, it is kept out of the defining expression for $K$, for simplicity. From the point of view of $G^0$ this is correct since the standard state to which the $G^0$ of water refers is pure liquid water, while the standard state for the other three species is 1M concentration.

> There's already a 1 molar concentration of hydronium ion IN solution under standard state conditions.

You're correct that for specifying the $G^0$ of $\ce{H3O+}$ the standard state is 1M. But the standard state of $\ce{H3O+}$ is not where the reaction takes place. The same $K$ will be found whether you add the $\ce{HNO3}$ to pure water or to a solution of $\ce{HCl}$ of pH zero -- the final concentrations of $\ce{H+}$, $\ce{NO3-}$ and $\ce{HNO3}$ will be different in the two cases, but $K$ will be the same.

---

You can find a good discussion of the "standard state" for ionic species in solution here: 
http://www.public.asu.edu/~laserweb/woodbury/classes/chm341/lecture_set10/lecture10.doc

I'll quote a couple of paragraphs.  You can see from this discussion that the calculation of these standard free energies is based exactly on the equilibrium constants, so the formula your professor used works almost by definition!

> As always, we can talk about the Gibbs free energy, enthalpy and entropy of such reactions. However, if we try to break these reactions down into the Gibbs energy, enthalpy and entropy of formation of each species in the reaction, we end up defining things like the Gibbs energy of a sodium cation in solution. Yet there is no way to generate just a sodium cation in solution (that would violate charge balance). Thus, we can only determine the Gibbs energy of formation of pairs of ions. This does not cause any real physical chemistry problems, but it causes a book keeping problem: how do we write down the Gibbs energy of formation of a Sodium cation in a book so that we can use it in any reaction where sodium cations are formed?
>
> The answer is that we come up with a sort of standard ion, $\ce{H+}$ (really something more like $\ce{ H3O+}$) and we define the free energy of formation of all other ions relative to this one. For example, I can measure the Gibbs energy change when I dissolve HCl in water to form $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$.
>   $$\ce{HCl}\text{(g)}\to\ce{H+}\text{(aq)}+\ce{Cl-}\text{(aq)}
>  \quad\Delta G^0{}_1
> $$
>   I can now just define the Gibbs energy of formation of $\ce{H+}$ as zero and then determine the relative Gibbs energy of formation of $\ce{Cl-}$.
>   $$\begin{align}&
> \Delta G^0{}_1=\Delta G^0_{\mathrm{F}}(\ce{H+})+\Delta G^0_{\mathrm{F}}(\ce{Cl-})-\Delta G^0_{\mathrm{F}}(\ce{HCl})
> \\&
> \Delta G^0_{\mathrm{F}}(\ce{H+})=0\quad\text{(definition)}\\&
> \Delta G^0_{\mathrm{F}}(\ce{Cl-})= \Delta G^0{}_1+\Delta G^0_{\mathrm{F}}(\ce{HCl})
> \end{align}
> $$

Comment: Standard state for solutions means having 1 molar solutions. Or in terms of activities, that means activity = 1.

Comment: Quite right; I had misunderstood your comment.  I've edited the answer to clarify what I meant.

Comment: They were standard free energies.

Comment: From the national bureau of standards.

Comment: So does this have any bearing on the found K value?

Comment: @Dissenter - I guess what I meant was whether he explained how these constants are derived.  I've added text to my answer to explain that.

Comment: @Dissenter - Yes it does have a bearing on the value of K.  It means that the definition of K (which is the same definition as K_a) is consistent with the definition of the standard free energies.

Comment: @Dissenter -- I think it's up to you now to explain why you think there is a problem.

Comment: My issue is that this delta g and K are for the dissociation of nitric acid in a solution already at pH of 0.0. That's not how Ka is defined.

Comment: @Dissenter -- I think I got what's worrying you! The same $K$ will be found whether you add nitric acid to pure water or to a highly acidic solution (or a basic one).  That's the "magic" of equilibrium constants -- they don't change much for a wide variety of concentration values.  (They change a bit -- then you have to use activities instead.)

Comment: I am puzzled a little bit. The equilibrium constant is defined via $$\Delta G^\circ = -RT\ln{}K,$$ which resolves to $$K=\frac{a(\ce{H3+O})a(\ce{NO3-})}{a(\ce{HNO3})a(\ce{H2O})}.$$ Now if we assume reasonably diluted systems we can write concentrations $$K=\frac{[\ce{H3+O}][\ce{NO3-}]}{[\ce{HNO3}][\ce{H2O}]} = \frac{K_a}{[\ce{H2O}]}.$$ Assuming that the concentration of water does not change, because it is diluted enough, wouldn't that mean that the $K_a$ is off by a factor of $(55.5~\mathrm{mol/L})^{-1}$?

Comment: Hi @Martin - I addressed this briefly in the answer. Solvent concentration is not part of the equilibrium constant, by convention. The standard values of $G^0$ for aqueous species are calculated using the same convention, so everything balances out.

Comment: Can you point me to the source of this convention, please. It is not given in the goldbook page for [equilibrium constant](http://goldbook.iupac.org/S05915.html).

Comment: Sure it is. It says there $K^0=e^{-\Delta_tG^0/RT}$. So the two are
consistent by definition. The rest follows from the observations in my
answer: the standard state for water is pure water, for the other
species it is 1M conc; for ions, there is a further
normalization relative to $\ce{H+}$. That is, tabulated
values of $G^0$ assume the fiction that the species
of interest is $\ce{H+}$ not $\ce{H3O+}$, and the reaction might
just as well be $\ce{HNO3 \leftrightharpoons H+ +NO3-}$. See problem 10
at http://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/genchem/topicreview/bp/ch21/gibbs.php
for an explicit example.

Comment: Interestingly (and coherently), I see that the Golden Book respects the same fiction in
its definition of the acidity constant: "The equilibrium constant for
splitting off the $n$th proton", rather than, for example, "for
transfering the $n$th proton to the solvent".  See http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00080.html